# Total steps of of long process, track completed steps, reuse query

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented

I have some long-time method (PrintInfo).

I need to know total steps of that method and track completed parts.

How to **reuse** same filtered query in:

1. **TotalSteps**  (ex, Program: progressMonitor.TotalSteps = /* ... */)
2. method **PrintInfo**?

**Description of example**: .

I have BookLibrary with some hierarchy( BookCabinet → Box → Book  → Words).

I need to print some information of filtered books and track completed parts. Printing can take long time.

**Entities**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TotalSteps
{
    class BookCabinet
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
    }

    class Box
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }

    class Book
    {
        public string[] Authors { get; set; }
        public List<string> Words { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ProcessMonitor**:

```
using System;

namespace TotalSteps
{
    class ProcessMonitor
    {
        public int TotalSteps { get; set; }

        private int completedSteps = 0;
        public int CompletedSteps
        {
            get
            {
                return completedSteps;
            }
            set
            {
                completedSteps = value;
                Console.WriteLine("Completed steps: " + completedSteps);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BooksLibrary**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TotalSteps
{
    class BooksLibrary
    {
        public void PrintInfo(IEnumerable<BookCabinet> cabinets, ProcessMonitor processMonitor)
        {
            if (!cabinets.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            cabinets = cabinets.Where(cabinet => cabinet.Category == "Biology");
            foreach (BookCabinet cabinet in cabinets)
            {
                IEnumerable<Box> boxes = cabinet.Boxes.Where(box => box.Category.Contains("fish"));
                if (boxes.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("BookCabinet category: " + cabinet.Category);
                }

                foreach (Box box in boxes)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Book> books = box.Books.Where(book => book.Authors.Contains("Mick"));
                    if (books.Any())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Box category: " + box.Category);
                    }

                    foreach (Book book in books)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> words = book.Words.Where(word => word.Contains("lionfish") || word.Contains("permission"));
                        if (words.Any())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Book authors: " + string.Join(", ", book.Authors));
                        }

                        foreach (string word in words)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("word: " + word);
                            processMonitor.CompletedSteps++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Program**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TotalSteps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessMonitor progressMonitor = new ProcessMonitor();
            List<string> words = new List<string>() { "lionfish", "permission", "trade" };
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>() { new Book() { Authors = new string[] { "Mick", "John" }, Words = words } };
            List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>() { new Box() { Category = "fish", Books = books }};

            IEnumerable<BookCabinet> cabinets = new List<BookCabinet>()
                {
                    new BookCabinet() { Category = "Archeology",  Boxes = new List<Box>() { } },
                    new BookCabinet() { Category = "Biology", Boxes = boxes },                   
                };
            BooksLibrary librarty = new BooksLibrary();
            progressMonitor.TotalSteps = cabinets.Where(cabinet => cabinet.Category == "Biology")
                .SelectMany(cabinet => cabinet.Boxes.Where(box => box.Category.Contains("fish"))
                .SelectMany(box => box.Books.Where(book => book.Authors.Contains("Mick"))))
                .SelectMany(book => book.Words.Where(word => word.Contains("lionfish") || word.Contains("permission"))).Count();

            Console.WriteLine("Total steps: " + progressMonitor.TotalSteps);
            librarty.PrintInfo(cabinets, progressMonitor);              
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: 
I duplicate code. It's not right.
Are there any better approaches to achieve what i want?

Maybe to store query in entities.

The problem is that If I edit method PrintInfo 
i will forget to change method to count total steps.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TotalSteps
{
    class BookCabinet
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<Box> Boxes { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Box> FilteredBoxes
        {
            get
            {
                return Boxes.Where(box => box.Category.Contains("fish"));
            }
        }
    }

    class Box
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Book> FilteredBooks
        {
            get
            {
                return Books.Where(book => book.Authors.Contains("Mick"));
            }
        }
    }

    class Book
    {
        public string[] Authors { get; set; }
        public List<string> Words { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> FilteredWords
        {
            get
            {
                return Words.Where(word => word.Contains("lionfish") || word.Contains("permission"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: `PrintInfo` is doing 2 things: searching and printing. So when you say 'printing can take (a) long time', which of these 2 do you mean?